# How to create dynamic provider in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Doesn`t show in page

```js
$scope.sayHi=function(provider) {
  $scope.Name=provider.Name
  console.log(provider)
 }
 
 $http.get("data.php")
    .success(function(response) {
     response.records.forEach(function($scope) {
      app.provider($scope.City , function () {
       return {
        $get:function() {
         return {
          Name:$scope.Name
         }
        }
       }
      })
     })
    });
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js">
  <input ng-model="city">
<p ng-click='sayHi(city)'>Click </p>
<p>This is name: {{name}}</p

> Blockquote**strong text**

</script>
```

Could i make a provider and accessed to it used the ng-model in page

Answer (score 0):

You can add a defined service/provider to your controller by injection.

Define it in your module:

```
app.provider("myProvider", ['$http', function($http) {
   getXyz: function(callback) {
      $http.get("data.php").success( callback );
   }
}]);
```

Btw it is not a good idea to start the names of your own functions with a $ sign becaus this is used by angularfor internal variables. There is a chance that name collide.

Then use it in your controller, there is no need to access it on your view.

```
app.controller( "myController", ['$scope', 'myProvider', function($scope, myProvider){
   $scope.sayHello = function(){     
      myProvider.getXyz(function(response) {
         $scope. ...
      });
   }
}
```